# iPhone - pushing a controller and switching tabs simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In a common iPhone configuration, my application's main window is a tab bar controller that contains multiple UINavigationController. My stumbling block now is pushing and changing controllers simultaneously: it appears that I can do both sequentially, but I have to press the tab again to have the view updated.

For example, I'm on tab 1, and I have a button that will load a new view on tab 2 that I want to present right away. Code for that is

```
tabController.selectedViewController = myListsController;
EditListViewController * editController = [[EditListViewController alloc] initWithList:l];
[myListsController.navigationController pushViewController:editController animated:YES];
```

With this code, the new tab is presented, but I don't see the new view. Can this be done?

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked. Please mark the my answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 2 tab views (and `myListsController.navigationController` is the root of your 2nd tab), you could do it like this:

```
UINavigationController *nc = myListsController.navigationController;
EditListViewController *editController = [[EditListViewController alloc] initWithList:l];
[myListsController.navigationController setViewControllers:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[nc viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0],editController,nil]];

NSMutableArray *vcs = [[tabController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[vcs replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:nc];
[tabController setViewControllers:vcs];
[vcs release];
[self.tabController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: I have 5 controllers, but something like this could work. I'm just struggling with how to do both at once so it is as seamless as possible.

Comment: You can do both at once with the code I provided. To the user it would be seamless.

Comment: Hey you're right. For some reason selecting a tab based on the object didn't work, but choosing an index did. I'll be sure to note this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
//your code
}
```

in you Viewcontroller class.